# Connection string for SQL Server in Julia ODBC

Tags: julia

In Julia, I use this code to connect to a Sql Server database, with no credentials
All good!

```
ODBC.adddsn("SQL_Server_DSN", "SQL Server"; SERVER="x", DATABASE ="x", Trusted_Connection="True")
conn = DBInterface.connect(ODBC.Connection, "SQL_Server_DSN")
cursor = DBInterface.execute(conn, "SELECT * FROM dbo.users")|> DataFrame
```

But when I try to use credentials, somehow I am not able to get how to adapt the connection string.
Any sugestions?

Comment: Christian, did you ever get this to work?  I'm having trouble as well, think I've made the connection to the sql server database but DBInterface.execute does not work.  Any chance you could post a copy of a DBInterface.execute line of code that actually works?  Thx. J.

Comment: This one works for me:

`conn2 = ODBC.Connection("Driver=SQL Server;SERVER=xx;DATABSE=xx;UID=xx;PWD=xx")

 results =DBInterface.execute(conn2, "SELECT * FROM x")|> DataFrame`

Comment: Wow, that actually works!  I think you might have a spelling error in "DATABASE"?  Just for interest I manged to get it to work with MS's "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" driver!  This is my working code.  Thx. J.  conn2 = ODBC.Connection("Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=66.66.66.66;DATABASE=myDB;UID=myUName;PWD=myPWD")
results=DBInterface.execute(conn2, "SELECT TOP 15 column FROM table")|> DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
ODBC.adddsn("SQL_Server_DSN", "SQL Server"; SERVER="x", DATABASE ="x", UID="sa", PWD="passwd")
```

I am not having currently SQL Server installed to test - however this should work. See also the notes below.

Notes:

- In Windows Control Panel -> ODBC you cab create a DSN manually and then use it from Julia (instead of `adddsn` command)
- DSN can be added manually in Windows Control Panel -> ODBC -> File DSN. In case of connection issues it is a good idea to start there, create something called "File DSN" and then have a look a at the created `*.dsn` file. This is the most convenient way to debug any ODBC connection.
- You normally do not want to create a DSN but you should use an ODBC connection directly. In your case this could look in the following way:

  ```
  conn = ODBC.Connection("Driver=SQL Server;SERVER=myServerAddress;DATABASE=myDataBase;UID=sa;PWD=passwd")
  ```

Comment: Your suggestion about using Connection directly works! Thanks!

Comment: It's another issue, but after I get the data, the string row is looking like this: "PL\0\0" instead of "PLN". Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Problem with character encoding or an ugly ODBC bug. Generally usage of ODBC is not recommended (not Julia related) - those drivers tend to have surprising issues. Try using dedicated Python drivers from Microsoft - this could be good option here. If possible select non ODBC ones. I have not been using MS SQL for more than 5 years though

Answer (score 2):

I finally got a working solution to this problem but it was quite difficult, primarily due to a lack of documentation for most of this.  I'm not convinced that the ODBC drivers are set up correctly but it works!  Thx for all suggestions.

```
julia> using ODBC

julia> using DBInterface

julia> using DataFrames

julia> ODBC.drivers()
Dict{String, String} with 4 entries:
  "unixODBC"                          => "Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2\0UsageCount=1\0"
  "ODBC Drivers"                      => ""
  "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"     => "Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1\0UsageCount=6\0"
  "unixODBC/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" => "Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1\0UsageCount=1\0"

julia> conn2 = ODBC.Connection("Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=ip#;DATABASE=DBName;UID=UserName;PWD=Passwd")
ODBC.Connection(Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=ip#;DATABASE=DBName;UID=UserName;PWD=Passwd)

julia> results=DBInterface.execute(conn2, "SELECT TOP 15 variable FROM table")|> DataFrame
15×1 DataFrame
 Row │ variable 
     │ String      
─────┼─────────────
   1 │ A81064
   2 │ A82027
   3 │ A82046
   4 │ A82055
   5 │ A83011
  ⋮  │      ⋮
  12 │ A84027
  13 │ A84030
  14 │ A84032
  15 │ A84033
     6 rows omitted

julia>
```